# Oracle APEX: TypeError: apex.region(...) is null when clicking a button

Tags: oracle-apex

I have an interactive gridwhere I need to bulk update a field in a bunch of selected records to the current date.

I tried to replicate the suggestion from this post https://ruepprich.wordpress.com/2017/03/23/bulk-updating-interactive-grid-records/ but my javascript is running an error in the first step - can't find the region (error TypeError: apex.region(...) is null)

:D

I've been away from APEX and coding for a while, so I'm struggling a little with this.

My region is named *breachbulkupdate*, my column is named *CORRESPONDENCE_SENT*, and I've created a button to run the below JavaScript code when clicked

```
var record;

var region = apex.region("breachbulkupdate");
console.log(region);

//Identify the particular interactive grid
var ig$     = apex.region("breachbulkupdate").widget();

//Fetch the model for the interactive grid
var grid    = ig$.interactiveGrid("getViews","grid");

//Fetch the model for the interactive grid
var model   = ig$.interactiveGrid("getViews","grid").model;

//Fetch selected records
var selectedRecords = apex.region("breachbulkupdate").widget().interactiveGrid("getViews","grid").view$.grid("getSelectedRecords");

//Set current date as correspondence sent date
var sentDate = new Date();

//Loop through selected records and update value of the salary column
for (i=0; i < selectedRecords.length; i++) {

   //Get the record
   record = model.getRecord(selectedRecords[i][0]);

   //Set Correspondence Sent Date
   model.setValue(record,"CORRESPONDENCE_SENT", sentDate);

}
```

You can see the name of the region is exactly the same, copied (ctrl+c, ctrl+v):
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jp4Ok.png)

Can you please give a help?

Thanks,

Guilherme

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is a very old blog.... I think quite a bit changed since then in the syntax.
Here is an example to increase the salary for a the selected records in an IG on the EMP sample table (with static id "emp"):

```
var i, records, record, sal, model,
        view = apex.region("emp").call("getCurrentView");

let percent = 10

    if ( view.supports.edit ) { // make sure this is the editable view
        percent = percent / 100;
        model = view.model;
        records = view.getSelectedRecords();
        for ( i = 0; i < records.length; i++ ) {
            record = records[i];
            sal = parseFloat(model.getValue(record, "SAL"));
            if ( !isNaN(sal) ) {
                sal = sal + sal * percent;
                model.setValue(record, "SAL", "" + sal); // turn the number back into a string!
            }
        }
    }
```

This example was copied from page 9 in the ig cookbook v6 app (google ig cookbook and download/install the app from John Snyders website. v6 is the latest version).

-- update:
The **static id** is key to implementing this. In the example above the static id of my interactive grid is "emp" and that is how it is referenced (`apex.region("emp")`). Note that "static id" is not the same as the region title...

[image]

This can easily be tested in the browser console with some javascript commands.

[image]

Observe that `apex.regions` lists the regions on the page. `apex_region("x")` returns null since that region does not exist and `apex_region("emp")` returns the region object. The 4th line references a non-existing region that throws the error you are seeing.

Comment: Hi thanks, I tried to reproduce the exact logic for the employ double salary with the employee table right now using the exact above java script code and I'm still having the error Uncaught TypeError: apex.region(...) is null.... I don't know exactly if there is any API broken on my APEX

Comment: Hey, I see what you mean, but I don't believe I'm using a wrong static id, I just updated my post with a screenshot. The static ID is exactly the same.

Comment: Did you run any of the commands that I added to my answer ? If you do, with that value you indicate it will error out. The command ```apex.regions``` will show you the ids of the regions on that page. The screenshot you posted shows the *title* of the region. In javascript, you need to reference the *static id* of the region - that is a region attribute and can be anything you want. By default it is null and then apex will use the internal component id that apex has in the database. I added a screenshot of where the static id is set for a region

Comment: I see what you mean now, I've missed this concept. I was thinking the title was the static ID, my mistake.

Comment: With static ID filled out it works :)

Comment: Glad you got it to work